# How to kill a process started by a script in the script itself?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, kill

I am a total noob in shell scripting. I am creating a `.sh` file with multiple commands, but my problem is that the last command is an executable file that after executing stays open and the processes keep running in the terminal until I close the terminal or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>\</kbd>. I want to kill these processes or quit the terminal which will also kill the process automatically while running the `.sh` file. This is the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ./var/www/testGraduationProject1/public/Hume2Compiler/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`
humec -lotsaspace tails.hume;
./tails > hello.txt
```

I have tried these two commands but they just stop the loading of process in terminal, but without closing the terminal or the process itself.

```
killall tails
stty -a | grep inter
```

Comment: You can send SIGQUIT with `kill -3 <pid>`. Not sure if that will do what you want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, but I assume you're asking how to make the `tails` command run for *N* seconds then kill it?

If so, use the `timeout` command (installed by default in 12.04).

Here's your script using `timeout` (removed some redundant code while I was at it). It runs `tails` for 10 minutes (600 seconds) before killing it with the TERM signal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PATH=$PATH:$PWD/var/www/testGraduationProject1/public/Hume2Compiler/bin
humec -lotsaspace tails.hume
timeout 600 tails > hello.txt
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068 for more information.

Comment: perfect this is better than what i needed. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put this line explicitly in the background:

```
./tails > hello.txt&
```

Then add

```
pkill tails
```